# Substr - Instr Function Error in Power BI

Tags: search, powerbi, dax, dashboard

I used the SEARCH function in Power BI but finds the location of the character I want to find incorrect.

The screenshot will tell you better.

[image]

Actually, I want to extract source system (android - ios etc). Essentially I can do with SQL using instr - substr but I want to use DAX Language.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this. I had to change the semicolon to a comma to separate the arguments.

You can use `MID` to return substrings, which takes the start position and length as arguments.

```
=var str_start = search("Twitter for",[source])
 var str_end = search("</a>",[source])
 return mid([source],str_start, str_end-str_start)
```

Comment: C. Rush and @Strawberryshrub, I replyed to your's answered above with comment.